# Facebook recommendations bar works on and off

Tags: facebook, debugging

My facebook recommendations bar gives this message:
*The parameter app_id is required*

But the app id is applied to the script, and I don't get any error message from the debugging tool. Only warning I get is that **og:image should be larger.**

What could possibly be wrong?

---

This is what facebook debugger tool says:

> **Open Graph Warnings That Should Be Fixed**
>   **Extraneous Property** Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'article:publisher'.
>
> **Parser Mismatched Metadata**     The parser's result for this metadata did not match the input metadata. Likely, this was caused by the data
>   being ordered in an unexpected way, multiple values being given for a
>   property only expecting a single value, or property values for a given
>   property being mismatched. Here are the input properties that were not
>   seen in the parsed result: 'article:publisher'